# Parse deep JSON object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using google maps API, and getting the response from google. Just need to get distance "text" value, e.g. 57.6 mi and duration "text" value where it is "1 hour and 1 min" from JSON that gets returned.

```js
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "blah blah" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "some address" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "57.6 mi",
                  "value" : 92652
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 hour 1 min",
                  "value" : 3664
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I have tried to parse it out by using dot notation and key-value pairs, but the deepest I could get is getting "rows" - which returned me object Object.

Comment: your `rows` has an array (of one element) inside it.  so you probably need `rows[0].elements[0].distance.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Claies beat me to it, you can get the distance using `data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text`

```js
var data = {
  "destination_addresses": ["blah blah"],
  "origin_addresses": ["some address"],
  "rows": [{
    "elements": [{
      "distance": {
        "text": "57.6 mi",
        "value": 92652
      },
      "duration": {
        "text": "1 hour 1 min",
        "value": 3664
      },
      "status": "OK"
    }]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}

document.write(data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text)
```

Comment: On the same token, in this syntax, data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text, if the "rows" in the source was something else, for example, 'foo', then it would be data.foo[0].elements[0].distance.text, or is it a syntax thing?

Comment: Yes, then it would be `data.foo[0].elements[0].distance.text`

Comment: OK, not to be too obtuse, but if in the source "elements" was let's say "bar", then it will be data.foo[0].bar[0].distance.text - - - it's just the "elements" sounds like part of the language, but coincidentally it is a property name, so that's what threw me off. Thanks again for your help.